# Google Forms Rename "File upload" File to "Question - Submitter"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I am using Google Forms to collect images from team members and I want to ensure that each file that is uploaded to Google Forms and saved in Google Drive has the same naming convention.

There are five ***File upload*** questions that team members are asked to upload their images to. The files are placed into Google Drive folders with random file names followed by `- firstName lastName`. On an ***onFormSubmit*** trigger I would like to change the names of the user-provided files to `fileUploadQuestionName - firstName lastName`.

I am pretty new to Google Apps Script and I have no idea how to go about doing this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

### You can change the name of the uploaded file on each form submit by the following process

- retrieve the last form response **onFormSubmit** with `form.getResponses()[LAST FORM SUBMISSION]`
- retrieve the ID of the uploaded file with `getItemResponses()[QUESTION NUMBER].getResponse()`
- open the file ID with DriveApp and change its name as desired

```
function myFunction() {
  var form=FormApp.getActiveForm();
// returns the total number of form submissions
  var length=form.getResponses().length;
//replace QUESTION NUMBER through the index of the question prompting the file upload - keep in mind that the first question has the index 0
  var id=form.getResponses()[length-1].getItemResponses()[QUESTION NUMBER].getResponse();
//getResponses()[length-1] retrieves the last form response, accounting for the fact that the first index is zero and hte last length-1
//gets the name of the question
  var fileUploadQuestionName=form.getResponses()[length-1].getItemResponses()[QUESTION NUMBER].getItem().getTitle();
//accesses the uploaded file
  var file=DriveApp.getFileById(id);
  name = file.getName();
//changes the file name
  var name = fileUploadQuestionName+' - '+name.split(' - ')[1]
  file.setName(name);
}
```

PS: If you want to change a posteriori the names of all the files submitted and not just the last files - you need to loop through all form responses:

```
for(var i=0;i<length;i++){ 
 var id=form.getResponses()[i].getItemResponses()[QUESTION NUMBER].getResponse();
  ...
 ...
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would likely be by either iterating through the specified folder in google drive on a time-based trigger and either checking if they meet your specified condition or moving them to a different folder after they're renamed.

```
function checkFile()
{
  var files = DriveApp.getFolderById('ID of Folder').getFiles(); 
// you can find this by going to form responses and clicking the link to an attached file and copying the id from the URL
// https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  var fileUploadQuestionName = 'Test';
  while(files.hasNext())
  {
    var file = files.next();
    var name = file.getName();
    if(name.indexOf(fileUploadQuestionName) == -1)
    {
      name = fileUploadQuestionName+' - '+name.split('-')[1]
      file.setName(name);
    }
  }
}
```

From there you'll need to add a time-based trigger to run every hour or day or minute depending on how critical it is to always find files of the correct name.

I can't find any documentation on accessing the file from within the response item on google's formApp documentation.