# Rename files in Google Drive that have been collected through Google Forms

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, file-rename

I am collecting Friends photos through a Google Form. The Form has only two fields Name (text) and Photo (upload).

The uploaded photo is stored in a folder in Google Drive and a hyperlink appears in the Google sheet to the name.

The issue I am facing is that the photo stored in Google Drive usually has a name generated while taking the photo and is not the name of the person whose photo it is. I want the photo file name to be the same as the person's name.

I don't know much of Google Scripts and would like help in using a script to rename the files in the Google Drive with the name of the uploader which is in the Google Sheet.

Comment: I think that the filename of files on Google Drive can be changed using Google Apps Script. But unfortunately, I cannot understand about `using a script to rename the files in the Google Drive with the name of the uploader which is in the Google Sheet.`. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue and your goal?

Comment: Thank You for offering help. 

Let me describe the problem with an example. Vijay Krishna fills in his name in the first field of the form and uploads his photo which bears the name "DSC224.jpg". 

In the Google Sheet a link like this is displayed in the Photo Column:

"https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xM0LF6zaKchmNjzKRept7ABV8SnX02LP". The file in the Google drive has the string "DSC224.jpg" in the name. 

I want the jpg file in the Google Drive to renamed as "Vijay Krishna.jpg"

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your replying, I cannot still see the vision of your situation and goal. I apologize for this. For example, can you provide the sample Google Form and Spreadsheet for replicating your situation? By this, I would like to try to understand your question. How about this?

Comment: Thanks. 

Here's a link to the Form. 
tinyurl.com/rsprename

Please try it out. Once, I have your email in the form, I will make you a collaborator so that you can better understand what I am wanting to do.

Comment: Please upload junk data to ensure your privacy/confidentiality etc. The real issue is file renaming...

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. When I could correctly understand about your question, I would like to try to think of the solution. I deeply apologize that I cannot resolve your issue soon.

Comment: The file is uploaded to the respondent's Drive, so the script should have access to this Drive if it were to rename the uploaded file. Since triggers (I guess an `onFormSubmit` trigger would be necessary here) run under the authority of the user who installed the trigger, this user should have access to the respondent's Drive. Could that be the case? Otherwise, if all users respondent's were from the same domain and you are the domain admin, you could try with a service account with domain-wide delegation. Can you please clarify about all this?

Comment: @lamblichus. The renaming of the files is not to be done in real time. After the process of form submissions is over, I need to update the file names with the names of the people (ie the value in another column) in one go. It is not a recurring activity. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand. `onFormSubmit` is not a time-based trigger (which could be fired recurrently), it will just run once every time the form is submitted. You don't want this? If you don't want this to run `onFormSubmit`, when and how is this script supposed to run, and while logged into which user, the respondent, or you?

Answer (score 0):

To rename uploaded files in Google Drive that have been collected through Google Forms you can

- create your own apps script that will process all files received via Google Form, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57730428/google-forms-rename-file-upload-file-to-question-submitter) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68050602/create-new-folder-for-each-google-forms-response), or
- use my Google Forms add-on [Form Uploads Manager](https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/app/form_uploads_manager/756774028129) that renames the uploaded files, move them to the Google Drive folders you specified and can add a description for each uploaded file, which makes it easy to find files using the built-in Google Drive search. A detailed description of the add-on settings is available on the app [home page](https://apps.myrout.es/fum).

*Disclaimer:* This is my Google Forms add-on, which I created for my own purposes, and after successful use I posted it on the Google Workspace Marketplace. After a 1 week trial (which might be enough to reach your goals), a paid add-on subscription is required.