# create new folder for each google forms response

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a google forms that I am looking to set up a script to transfer each response to its own folder.

trigger would be a new response. When triggered, it would create a subfolder within a parent folder with a name based off a specific column answer.

I would need it to transfer responses to a google doc in the subfolder and also transfer any file uploads into the subfolder.

currently, I have the script from this website installed https://www.labnol.org/file-uploads-folder-google-forms-201226. When in the script editor it runs without error. However, it is not creating a new folder or transferring uploads to that folder.

It is however, renaming the submitted uploads to match the name of who submitted it.

Comment: Yes I believe it's possible.  You can probably run you script from onFormSubmit trigger. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events

Comment: Just to confirm: Did you create the installable trigger that should be executed when the form is submitted? https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually

Comment: I just deleted and started from scratch and it is working correctly now.

can you help me with where to modify so that it names the subfolder based off a specific response? in this case, column D.

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger the automation by setting up an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#google_apps_triggers) to monitor [submissions to the form](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit_1).

Once it is triggered, it'll run the function you specify when creating the trigger and pass an [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit_1) to it.
This event object has data about the submission, including the [responses](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item-response).

After that, based on the responses, you can [create a folder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#createfoldername) with the specified name and [move uploaded files](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#movetodestination) to it.

For example, consider a job application form with two questions, "Name of applicant" and "CV file upload". You can create a folder for the applicant and move the uploaded file to it with the following function:

```
function processApplication(event) {
  // Parent folder for all application
  const applicationsFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('ABC123');
  
  // Get respondent's name and uploaded file
  const response = event.response.getItemResponses();
  const applicantName = response[0].getResponse();
  const uploadedFileID = response[1].getResponse();
  const uploadedFile = DriveApp.getFileById(uploadedFileID);

  // Create applicant's folder and move uploaded file to it
  const applicantFolder = applicationsFolder.createFolder(applicantName);
  uploadedFile.moveTo(applicantFolder);
}
```

Comment: thank you, it would applied to the spreadsheet correct?

I had seen this, but when i followed his instructions, it didnt work. 

https://www.labnol.org/file-uploads-folder-google-forms-201226

Comment: The code in my answer doesn't require a spreadsheet. The link you posted should also work well. What do you mean by "it didn't work"? What error did you get?

Comment: There was no initialize option when I copy and pasted it as he instructed.

Comment: It also tells me that i cant create a trigger with no function

Comment: hi! I was able to get the linked script to work. somewhat, itll run in the script  but when I submit on the form, it doesnt populate a folder etc. 

also, How do I go about setting the name of the folder based on a response?

 const subfolderName = response.getId();

do I just add the column number into this line?

Comment: Edit the question and post the working script you have, so it's easier for people to make suggestions.

Comment: tried my  best to edit. I wasnt sure how to enter the code and it kept giving me a n error even with the shortcut is says to use.

Comment: When I add your function to script editor inside my google form, there is an error... "TypeError: Cannot read property 'response' of undefined"